# conversion tracking:how conversion tracking tools oversome cookie limits

Tags: email, cookies, tracking

how conversion tracking tools oversome cookie limits? cookies have size and number limitations in browser. Do conversion tracking tools use one cookie per click or one cookie per customer account and set and update same cookie for each click?